# Can I assume that calling the destructor will not cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, winrt-xaml

I'm developing an app for the Windows Store called [myTrip](http://www.mytriptravelapp.com) and I'm having memory leaks on the app. I don't have any static classes with any Event handler around there, so the memory leaks aren't because of events.

I have some behaviors attached to a Bing Map control. And I think they stay attached there. Because of that I checked wether the destructor of those behaviors where being called or not. And they are being destroyed properly. This is the way I check that the control doesn't leak. But since I continue having leaks, I'm geting crazy searching for them.

So I checked with Just Trace, that some controls, that where being destroyed, where still in memory!  I suppose that and object is destroyed because the GC released it from memory, and that only happens when no other object references it, so, I wouldn't have any memory leaks. This is quite wierd, any clues on what's happening?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16273 - CLR Profiler

Comment: Are you disposing everything that implements IDisposable? If you can, wrap such code in a using block.